# How can I give my dog Vigilance to Lucia?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I give Vigilance to Lucia? I've adopted her and Blaine and they live in Breezehome, she asked to keep it but the only yes response was yes once I didn't need Vigilance anymore and there's no option to give him to her immediately. I've already let Blaine adopt a skeever will that effect anything?

Comment: I have adopted Blaine he has the skeever and I have adopted Lucia who wants Vigilance I will try to do that thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try telling Vigilance to leave you. It should say something like "You need to go home, dog". Afterwards, it will count it as him not being in your services, letting Lucia keep it. I am not sure, However, I am not sure whether Blaine owning a skeever could affect this.